# Joomla Variables for optional Profile Fields?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, user, profile

I have enabled some optional profile fields for the registered users of my website (using the **User-Profile plugin**), What are the Joomla variable which will return the value of these fields? 
I mean, if we want to display the name of the logged in user, we use `$user->username`variable.
I want to display the following optional fields : 
**City**
**Country** 
**Website** 
**About Me**

Which variables will return the value of these optional fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple bit of code to use as shown below

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);

echo '<p>City: ' . $profile->profile['city'] . '</p>';
echo '<p>Country: ' . $profile->profile['country'] . '</p>';
echo '<p>Website: ' . $profile->profile['website'] . '</p>';
echo '<p>About me: ' . $profile->profile['aboutme'] . '</p>';
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: thank you Lodder! :) now please help with my other question which is still unanswered.